# How to programatically make a button for each child of a datasnapshot?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to iterate through each child of *'results'* and programmatically make a button for them with the date as text. When u click on a button it will show an `ImageView` (the long string u see is a Base64 string which will be decoded into an image). Each child of *'results'* has a Base64 string.

I think I have to work with a `for loop` where I loop through every child of *'results'* and make a button for each child. Inside each button there will be different `ImageViews`.

I wasn't able to find any good solution, anyone has an idea?

**Database tree**
[image]

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen alright!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ever heard of [recyclerview](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview). You come to know that with the help of single code to make multiple views.

You can read more details about recyclerview on [Android Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview). It will make dynamic views for data.

Comment: I will look into this!